# AWS RDS Audit logging CFN

Tags: aws-cloudformation

How can one turn on audit logging for RDS via Cloudformation when we setup the RDS instance?

The only way I have seen so far is to setup the instance and then to modify it and check the Audit logging box to forward logs to CW. Can we do this for MySQL when we setup the instance and not having to modify it?

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly available from cloudformation, you need to create a custom resource to enable the logs.

I have created a custom resource to enable logs after the DB instance is created. Here are the cloudformation template and the Boto3 script.

https://gist.github.com/sudharsans/ab950c43f2086801d19b016f73310832